# Strategy for a fixed table header when you can't use JQuery and have very limited CSS capabilities

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I need a strategy for a fixed table header,

here are the strategies that have not worked for me, mainly because of certain functionality contraints:

- Copying the header and move the header according to the scrolltop

(the issue I have with this one is because of the input texts that are in the header. When I clone the header, it also clones the input form, the server-side always get the wrong session values.)

- Using the overflow-y and have the content scroll

(the problem with this one is because of the cell sizes, some of the cell sizes are dependent on  the size of the header. Therefore, when I do position:absolute, the size of the cells doesn't correspond to the size of the headers. Assigning a fixed length is really thought because the cells are generated dynamically)

PS: don't ask me why I didn't use a jQuery plugin, I have to code on top of the legacy code. I'm plainly running out of ideas.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to refactor.

Comment: I had an idea, which was to retrieve the cell widths from the header and then somehow resize the body cells... it's a bit over the top... but if anyone has a better idea, I'm all open to suggestions :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

[Refer this](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html/) (not my suggestion)

This works for me (on chrome and firefox). I guess its very bad approach but worth sharing.

**Markup:**

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>head1</th><th>head2</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>row1 col1</td><td>row1 col2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row2 col1</td><td>row2 col2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**CSS:**

```
    table{
        height:2000px;
    }
    thead tr {
         position:fixed;
         left:0;
         top:0;
    }
```

---

**Edit** (after comments)

**Markup:**

```
<div id='wrapper'>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>head1</th><th>head2</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>row1 col1</td><td>row1 col2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>row2 col1</td><td>row2 col2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
        height:500;
        overflow:scroll;
        width:400px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:Gray; 
    }
    table{
        height:2000px; 
    }
    thead tr {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that one before, unfortunately, I have to mention another problem. The table is inside a <div> popup, when I use position:fixed on a header, it appears outside the <div> popup. So the fixed position was a no for me... :*(

Comment: In addition, I tried playing with the z-index, hoping that it would not overflow the <div> popup. I guess I'm not familiar enough to make it work :S

Comment: Edited my answer, check now :)

Comment: Oh, by using fixed, there's another problem... The fixed header will become responsive to the page scroll and not the <div> popup; therefore when the user scrolls using the "other scroll" the fixed header still moves

Comment: Nevermind, I was just using the thead, not thead tr, but I remember trying it before though... I don't believe thead tr will have a fixed header in firefox

Comment: Then, you can change the `position` of `thead tr` from `absolute` to `fixed` on `div` scroll.

Comment: I just tried it, with the wrapper, it doesn't seem to have any fix headers (I tried both `fixed` and `absolute`)

Comment: It works in firefox. For any easy approach, I've attached a link. Use that.

Comment: this is what I typed:


`<style>
 #wrapper{ 
  width:2200px;
  float:left; 
  height:500px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
 }
  
 #wrapper thead tr{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:grey;
 }
</style>`

Comment: yeah I tried that one before as well, the problem that arose with the size of the cells. The <tbody> cells and the <thead> cells were completely unaligned.